# Getting problem while implementing swipe to reply in react native, using react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to access `item.user?.uid === currentUser?.uid` inside this `useAnimatedGestureHandler({})`
I want to do this because all message that are sent are getting swipped at once, one message should swipe at once.
Everything is working fine, just getting this issue.

```js
function YourComponent() {
.
.
. //rest of the code is fine
....
 
  const eventHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (event, ctx) => {

    },
    onActive: (event, ctx) => {
      x.value = <<item.user?.uid === currentUser?.uid >> ? 50 : -50; //I want to access `item.user?.uid === currentUser?.uid ` this thing here
    },
    onEnd: (event, ctx) => {
      x.value = withSpring(startingPosition);
    }
  });
.
..// rest of the code is fine
.. 

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={{ transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }] }}
      data={messageList}
      keyExtractor={(_, i) => i.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <FlingGestureHandler
          direction={item.user?.uid === currentUser?.uid ? Directions.LEFT : Directions.RIGHT}
          
          onGestureEvent={eventHandler} /**look here**/
          
          onHandlerStateChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
            if (nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
              swipeToReply(item.message, isLeft);
            }
          }}
        >
          {/* Your FlatList item content */}
        </FlingGestureHandler>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```